# Merging collections using LINQ while overriding rows with same ID

Tags: c#, linq

I got two collections of objects.

For example:

```
List<Foo> firstFoos = new List<Foo>();
List<Foo> secondFoos = new List<Foo>();

firstFoos.Add(new Foo() { Id = 1, ValueA = 10, ValueB = 15 });
firstFoos.Add(new Foo() { Id = 2, ValueA = 20, ValueB = 25 });
firstFoos.Add(new Foo() { Id = 3, ValueA = 30, ValueB = 35 });
firstFoos.Add(new Foo() { Id = 4, ValueA = 40, ValueB = 45 });

secondFoos.Add(new Foo() { Id = 1, ValueA = 100, ValueB = 150 });
secondFoos.Add(new Foo() { Id = 2, ValueA = 200, ValueB = 250 });
```

Using LINQ, how can I merge the two collection overriding `firstFoos` by `secondFoos` which have the same ID?

Expected result is:

```
|   Id    | ValueA | ValueB |
|---------|--------|--------|
|    1    |   100  |   150  |
|    2    |   200  |   250  |
|    3    |   30   |   35   |
|    4    |   40   |   45   |
```

Please note that this example case has only two value columns (`ValueA` and `ValueB`), but an actual case could have many more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd convert it to an `Id -> Foo` dictionary, and then just update with a regular foreach:

```
var fooDict = firstFoos.ToDictionary(foo => foo.Id, foo => foo);
foreach (var foo in secondFoos) 
    fooDict[foo.Id] = foo;
var newFoos = fooDict.Values.OrderBy(foo => foo.Id).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define a custom equality comparer and use `Union()`:

```
public class FooComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
{
    public bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Foo obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var mergedList = secondFoos.Union(firstFoos, new FooComparer())
                           .ToList();
```

This uses the fact that items in `secondFoos` are added to the resulting enumeration before any item in `firstFoo`, any item in `firstFoo` with an already existing Id will hence be filtered out. This assumes of course that `Id` should be distinct across all items.

Comment: Is this guaranteed to return the elements from secondFoos when both exist? Also, your GetHashCode method needs to return obj.Id (or a hash only related to the id).

Comment: @Random832: That's how Linq to Objects currently works yes - as specified in the docs **Union enumerates first and second in that order and yields each element that has not already been yielded.** and yes - hashcode is only over the `Id` property since this is the only property relevant for this comparer.

Comment: I could swear when I looked at it earlier it only had obj.GetHashCode. I saw that statement, but was/am unsure that it implies that it can't yield the object from the second collection [firstFoos] _in its place in the first collection's order_. I think the issue for me is that it doesn't sufficiently pin down what "each element" means given a non-default equivalence relation. I don't doubt it _currently_ works that way, it's just not clear that the spec guarantees it always will.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
var concat = firstFoos.Select(x => new { Foo = x, list=1 })
                      .Concat(secondFoos.Select(x => new { Foo = x, list= 2 });

var merge = from x in concat
            group x by x.Foo.Id into x
            select x.Count() == 1 ? x.First().Foo : x.First(y => y.list == 2).Foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = secondFoos.Concat(
    firstFoos.Except(secondFoos, 
    new LambdaComparer<Foo>((a, b) => a.Id == b.Id)))
    .ToList();
```

Another option, because you can never have too many solutions to the same problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
var f1NotInF2 = from f1 in firstFoos
    where !secondFoos.Exists(f2 => f1.Id == f2.Id)
    select f1;
var mixed = f1NotInF2.Concat(secondFoos);
```

Comment: Adding `OrderBy` will make the perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
            List<Foo> newFoos = new List<Foo>();
            Foo selected = null;
            foreach (Foo foo in firstFoos)
            {
                selected = secondFoos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == foo.Id);
                if (selected != null)
                {                   
                    newFoos.Add(selected);                   
                }
                else
                {

                    newFoos.Add(foo);
                } 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
var merged = firstFoos.Where(f => !secondFoos.Any(s => s.Id == f.Id))
    .Union(secondFoos).OrderBy(c=>c.Id);
```